# Amount vs amounts?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns, word-usage

When does we use **"amounts"**? 
Is my sentence " Ireland generated small amounts of waste. " correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need **a small amount** of milk in this recipe (generally implies a single dose). Same application for Ireland's small amount (viewed as a total amount).

I need **to add small amounts of milk** (probably need to add gradually, while cooking). Ireland's small amounts of waste were being promptly disposed of throughout the year.

Answer (score 2):

The singular and the plural have different meanings. 'Ireland generated a small amount of waste', would be the former whilst, 'Ireland generated small amounts of waste', would be the latter.

The first has the meaning of a single 'mound' or collection of waste, perhaps in the context of the country's total waste production in a year. On the other hand, the second has the idea of multiple gatherings of waste, perhaps in the context of presenting the idea of continual waste generation. It depends on if it's a single quantity or multiple individual quantities.